# String-manipulation in PHP, insert array keys in user defined string

Tags: php, string

I have a function that takes the input of a user defined string and an array of data (key=>value), which looks like this;

```
$text = "Hi! My name is @name, and I live in @location.";
$dataArray = array("name" => "Mikal", "location" => "Oslo, Norway");

function MakeString($text, array $dataArray)
{
// return manipulated string...
}
```

I would like my function to swap the string @variables with data from the array, where string-variable matches array-key (if it does), so that the function returns:

`"Hi! My name is Mikal, and I live in Oslo, Norway."`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    foreach($dataArray as $key=>$value)
    {
     $text= str_replace("@".$key,$value,$text);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! Would you consider preg_replace instead of str_replace in this situation? Maybe some performance improvements, or what do you think?

Comment: I don't really think that preg_replace will be more efficient... in fact php.net says that : "If you don't need fancy replacing rules (like regular expressions), you should always use this function instead of ereg_replace() or preg_replace()."

Comment: @MikalBen do you need these improvements? Or you're asking "just in case?" If so - forget PHP at all, write in machine codes directly into RAM. It would be significantly faster. If you don't have idea what it is - don't ask such questions anymore.